# Is there an explicit conformal map from ellipsoids to the plane or from ellipsoids to spheres?

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry, ellipsoids

I just stumbled upon conformal maps (never heard about them before) by accident. And it seems I may be able to solve a problem I have been working on with them.

For this I need to find an explicit conformal map from an arbitrary ellipsoid to either a plane or a sphere, however merely searching the web for such a map isn't returning anything useful.

I am wondering if anyone knows of an explicit, bijective, conformal map from an arbitrary ellipsoid to either of the described manifolds.

Comment: Scale the space along the directions of the principal directions of the ellipsoid so as to make them equal.  In statistics this is called "whitening."  Look it up.

Comment: Every surface is *locally* conformally equivalent to the Euclidean plane via [isothermal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_coordinates#Isothermal_coordinates_on_surfaces). Clearly there is no *global* conformal equivalence between a sphere/ellipsoid and plane, since they are not homeomorphic. I'm not sure if spheres and ellipsoids are globally equivalent, though.